# Mysql Huge tables , issues with count(*) being slow

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a big table with 4m rows. I have a very good machine with a lot of memory (16gb and 12 cpus). Data are changed each few hours and all at same time.

I have a table named enemy and one of the fields is power, that is a BIG INT field (64 bits) with an index.

I have a simple search to determine the position based in power

```
SELECT count(*) FROM enemy WHERE Power>value
```

When value is one of the higher values it is fast calculating the number of elements.... when Power is one of the last values, it is a lot of times slower finding the value.

I suppose that it needs to count how many elements match the condition but if the field is indexed (and ordered), I dont get why it is not instant or close to instant.

Is there any change that I can do to the index/field/search or do I need to create another column with current position?

3 queries examples with times and position returned:

```
"Select count(*) as n FROM Enemies WHERE Power > 900000000" 0.0053 seconds (Position 29654) 
"Select count(*) as n FROM Enemies WHERE Power > 100000000"  0.1089 seconds (Position 706266)
"Select count(*) as n FROM Enemies WHERE Power > 1900000"  0.3360 seconds (Position 2192063)
```

Comment: typo error (copy/paste from 2 queries). fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can somewhat improve performance with an index on `enemy(power)`.  The index will be scanned instead of the data pages.

Also, the `order by` makes no sense in a query that returns one row.  In fact, it should generate a syntax error.

Comment: it has an index already as i said. Yes, removing that it is a copy paste and i forgot to remove taht.